# Draw a rectangle over a background image in HTML5 Canvas on Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, html5-canvas

I want to draw a rectangle over a background image on canvas using angular.js. I can draw it by placing the rectangle code inside the image.onload function.But I want them to be separated.How can I do it?

```
$scope.printStars = function() {
                var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                c.width=1920;
                c.height=1080;

                var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 800);


                ctx.scale(c.width/1920,c.height/1080);
                ctx.translate(1920-500,0);
                 var imagePaper = new Image();


               imagePaper.onload = function(){


                    ctx.drawImage(imagePaper,100, 20, 500,500);



                };
                ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 200, 200);

                imagePaper.src = "Img/Back1.jpg";





            }
```

My code works if I do this

```
 imagePaper.onload = function(){


                    ctx.drawImage(imagePaper,100, 20, 500,500);
                    ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 200, 200);


                };
```

But I want the drawrectangle code outside of image function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the `ctx` to a variable on the `$scope` and access it in other places now. For example:

```
$scope.drawRectangle = function() {
  $scope.ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 200, 200);
}
```

```html
<button ng-click=drawRectangle()>Draw rectangle</button>
```

Comment: But I dont want any button to call that function. Is it possible to do it without using button?

Comment: Yes, the button was just an illustration. As long as you assign it to $scope, you can draw on the canvas from anywhere